# Queue up a Laravel event subscriber

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, events, queue, laravel-queue

I'm handling multiple events through an Event Subscriber instead of making separated Events/Listeners. I want to queue several of these events, but I haven't found a way to accomplish that. I've followed the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#event-subscribers), but there is no example how to choose what events I want to queue (not all the subscribers).

Any suggestions? (No individual Event/Listener, please)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If anyone is interested in, I've found the solution looking deeper in the Event Dispatcher.

Implementing the contract ShouldQueue on the EventSubscriber works the same than a separated Event/Listener and enqueue the events on the database. This should be documented in the official site.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for this! I agree, it should be explicit in the docs. I'm assuming there's no way to have an Event Subscriber class contain some events which are queued and some which are not?

Comment: Thanks ! I was looking for a way to use event subscriber with queues but wasn't sure it would work as it isnt specified in the docs

Comment: i have to add, if your shouldDiscoverEvents returns true in your EventServiceProvider, then this EventSubscriber which implements ShouldQueue makes the message duplicated if you write subscribe method inside with a mapping of listened Event. So choose one. If you auto discover events, then return void and do nothing in eventSubscriber's subscribe() method. Or vice versa